# Wicked_pdf and wkhtmltopdf in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

So we've had this working in many places with no problem. Locally works like a charm. But the last two places we've deployed our application to we installed wkhtmltopdf and cannot get wicked_pdf to work properly.

wkhtmltopdf location:

```
$ which wkhtmltopdf
=> /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

Our wicked_pdf configuration:

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  :exe_path => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
}
```

The error:

```
RuntimeError (Failed to execute:
"/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf" -q  --footer-html "file:///tmp/wicked_footer_pdf.html20140604-7480-1ag3z4u"    --margin-top 20 --margin-bottom 40  --page-size "Letter" --encoding "utf8" --print-media-type    - -
Error: PDF could not be generated!):
  app/controllers/concerns/downloadable_controller.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in download'
  app/controllers/concerns/downloadable_controller.rb:18:in `download'
```

I'm starting to think its b/c of an updated version of wkhtmltopdf or something b/c the last to deploys were a lot more recent than the previous ones that work fine. But these newer servers 64bit systems rather than 32bit as the previous servers were.

**=== EDIT ===**

After some further testing I'm seeing that its the footer that is breaking the whole thing, but I can't figure out why.

```
  def download
    # build resources such as @letter or @study to be used in view
    build_resources_for_pdf

    respond_to do |format|
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf => file_name,
               :template => "/#{model}/pdf/show.haml",
               :encoding => "utf8",
               :page_size => "Letter",
               :show_as_html => params[:debug].present?,
               :print_media_type => true,
               :margin => { :bottom => 40, :top => 20 },
               :footer => get_footer

      end
    end
  end

  def get_footer
    {
      :html => {
        :template => "studies/pdf/pdf_footer",
        :locals => {:study => @study}
      }
    }
  end
```

Comment: Are you using HTML5 `footer` tag by any chance?

Comment: Also what OS is your development and what OS is your production? I had a similar problem and have experienced that sometimes you need different executable for development and production.

Comment: What I'd do is capture the HTML for your page, throw it into a file, and use `wkhtmltopdf` directly. That will likely give you more information on what's going wrong.

Comment: I am not using the <footer> tag, osX 10.9 locally and centos 6.5 in production.

Comment: adding ?debug=true to the url the page loads as it should w/o errors...

Comment: Which versions of wkhtmltopdf are installed?